# Swift 5 - Navigation Pages

Tags: ios, swift

I am just getting to work with Swift 5 and have to update my apps. I use....

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to push users from a sign-in screen to the main app, yet with the updates here's how it looks below (iPhone currently in dark-mode)...

Some questions. What is this functionality definitively called? and how do I go about manipulating it? Say I want to remove it because right now if the user is in the main app they can swipe down and go back to the sign-in screen which would definitely cause problems.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Sign-In View Controller Code**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import RealmSwift

class StartViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Check if user is already logged-in so they don't have to sign-in again
    checkUserSignIn()

    // Setting textfield delegates so user can press enter and go to next textfield
    self.email.delegate = self
    self.password.delegate = self

    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    print(uid)
    print("printing the uid here")

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Add a background view to the table view
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "startBackground")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}

// Check if user is already signed-in, if so push to main app
func checkUserSignIn() {
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if (user != nil) {
            Database.database().reference().child("users").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    print("user is logged in")
                    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.email.text == "" || self.password.text == "" {

        //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {
                //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                print("You have successfully logged in")

                // Proceed To App
                func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                    if(segue.identifier == "home") {
                    } else {
                        print("Problem sending user into nature app")
                    }
                }

            } else {

                //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    // Check user has entered text into fields
    guard let email = email.text, email != "",
        let password = password.text, password != ""

        else {
            // Throw alert message to user if fields are empty
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration Error", message: "Please make sure you filled in all of the boxes to complete registration!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
    }

    // Register a new user on Firebase
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        // Throw registration error / Account could already exist
        if let error = error {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        guard let userID = user?.user.uid else {
            return
        }

        // Database reference
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        // Set user information to firebase data structure
        let userInfo = fireUsersData(email: email, profPicString: "", uid: userID)
        databaseRef.child("users").child(userID).updateChildValues(userInfo.getUserDictionary(), withCompletionBlock: { (err, databaseRef) in

            let UserToAdd = realmUserData()
            UserToAdd.email = email
            UserToAdd.uid = userID
            //UserToAdd.saveDataToRealm()

            if err != nil {
                // Throw error is problem completeting
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: (err?.localizedDescription)! as String, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    })

    // Dismiss keyboard
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    // Proceed To App
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "home") {
        } else {
            print("Problem sending user into nature app")
        }
    }
}
// END OF FILE
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before presenting your ViewController give this option:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For ignoring dark mode style in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** write this:

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
  }
```

**UPDATE:** Replace present to this code:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: So this kind of works. Problem is that the sign-in screen's navigation bar title text is still present within the main app and overlapping the current title text.

Comment: Going through the rest of the app, the sign-in navigation bar is still present throughout the app.

Comment: This solution has removed the ability to just swipe down and return to the sign-in screen yet the bar is now still present throughout the whole app and overlapping title text.

Comment: And also added an image of the storyboard of how it segues over.

Comment: @LukasBimba can you present your Home on navigation bar and tell me result? 
**self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)**

Comment: So replace "self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)" with "self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)" ?

Comment: But if I were you, I would change the app's root view controller to homeVC  after registration.

Comment: So what happens is that the navigation bar with the title "all about nature" is static and then the main app animates and layers over. Thus, seeing the overlapping titles.

Comment: let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc

Comment: Thank you, this works. Please add it to your answer.

Comment: keyWindow is deprecated.

Comment: @LukasBimba Yes you right it's in iOS 13 I didn't know, but you can get your window from AppDelegate         
 **let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc**